# How to describe DTO with nested entity?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to save DTO with id of nested entity, but I am getting a problem:
`Argument of type 'CreateSpendingDto' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DeepPartial<Spending>[]'.`
How should I describe my DTO for pass it only with id?

My entity is:

```js
@Entity('spending')
export class Spending {
  @Column()
  amount: number

  @ManyToOne(() => Category)
  @JoinColumn()
  category: Category

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number
}
```

My DTO is:

```js
export class CreateSpendingDto {
  readonly amount: number
  readonly category: number
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer, have to add a separate column with categoryId:

```js
  @ManyToOne(() => Category)
  @JoinColumn({name: 'categoryId'})
  category: Category

  @Column()
  categoryId: number
```